# Alice Carousel onSlideChanged not working with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, carousel

I'm currently creating a practice project using Alice Carousel. I've used the first set of code shown [here](https://maxmarinich.github.io/react-alice-carousel/#custom-components) as reference, except that I used Redux instead of useState for the values.

However, upon clicking thumbnails on my work, it seemed that the `onSlideChanged` function for the thumbnails is not working. On checking Redux Dev tools, the action for clicking the thumbnail runs white sync thumbs does not.

[image: Thumbnail clicking actions running, but Sync thumbs function is not]

Is using Redux here affecting Alice Carousel?

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you'll a snippet or at least the relevant code that handles the thumb_click

Comment: It's really the same with the link I added, just that it's being called with `dispatch` since I'm trying out Redux